# Creating already resolved Promise with static value - why execution is still asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

```
Promise.resolve("resolved").then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result)
});
console.log("promise created");
```

results in:

```
"promise created"
"resolved"
```

My question is: why execution is still async? What is happening behind the scenes of a Promise?

If I wrap `console.log` in `setTimeout` with delay `0`, then promise resolution happens before `console.log`

Comment: Because promises are always asynchronous.

Comment: Invariant behavior == less hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: see also [What is the intention behind clause 2.2.4 of Promise/A+ spec?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36932244/1048572)

Comment: Because once you enter the async world there is no way out unless you time travel to the future. I guess you have to study the event queues and job queues of JS. Then it will automatically make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial call to `Promise.resolve(...)` is synchronous, but anything that you chain off of in in a `.then()` block will *always* be async due to the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) implemented under the hood.

Your `console.log("promise created");` is called outside of your promise chain and is therefore executed immediately after thee initial Promise.resolve(...) call.

Since your `console.log("promise created");` outside of your promise chain, as soon as the initial call to `Promise.resolve(...)` occurs, the console log is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's answer focuses on technical implementation - thanks a lot. I want post additional answer that focuses on "why" with respect to the JavaScript concurrency model (I realized it when watching **Modern Asynchronous JavaScript** on Pluralsight.

So let's imagine piece of code:

```js
let progressStatus;

function opThatReturnsPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}

opThatReturnsPromise().then(function() {
  console.log(progressStatus = "Done");
})

console.log(progressStatus = "In progress...");
```

If "static" Promises were resolved synchronously, then this piece would result in output:

```
Done
In progress...
```

This is because of [Run-to-completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion). So ensuring asynchronicity, ensures consistent behaviour - no matter what is actually happening in the operation that is encapsulated by the Promise object.