# Why does MutationObserver not detect nodes after a random point?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, tampermonkey, userscripts, mutation-observers

I am building a `Tampermonkey` user script. My actual script is a lot more complex but I am able to reproduce with the following example.

My script needs to work on Hacker News website.

For example on this page:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39778570

Their html has `.athing` class which contains each comment. For each such class, I need to do a certain task (not relevant to this question). I am using `MutationObserver` to observe for those nodes in my user script:

My user script is this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         HN
// @namespace    https://news.ycombinator.com/*
// @version      2024-02-02
// @description  For Hacker News
// @author       Bobby
// @match        https://news.ycombinator.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==


const recordObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {

    mutations.forEach(m => {

        if (m.type === "childList" && m.addedNodes) {
            m.addedNodes.forEach(target => {

                if (target.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    target.querySelectorAll(`.athing:not([read_123])`).forEach (element=> {

                        element.setAttribute(`read_123`, true);

                        element.style.background = '#00FF0055';

                        console.log(element.id);
                    });
                }


            });
        }
    });
});

recordObserver.observe(document, {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    characterData: false,
    subtree: true
});
```

Notice how once detected, my script changes the background color of that element.

This seems to work fine to a certain point.

It randomly stops working at random nodes. This screenshot shows the issue:

[image]

Notice how it detected until the comment `Yoga is great but only really supports flexbox. For.....` after which it stopped detecting and also stopped printing the `id` in console.

If I access the same page again, it stops at different node.

How can I pin point what exactly is causing this issue?

Note that this issue isn't specific to `Tampermonkey`. My actual issue is occurring on iOS WKWebView where a user inserted script shows the same issue. I am able to reproduce this on desktop this way.

Answer (score 0):

MutationObserver callbacks are async so loading the script as a user one plus hoping it will trigger on loading DOM from the original page source is not a perfect idea. The whole venture doesn't work in Firefox for example.

Here I've explained in more details: [Why mutation observer is processed with microtask queue and not macrotask queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181757/why-mutation-observer-is-processed-with-microtask-queue-and-not-macrotask-queue/78182460#78182460)

To mitigate in Chrome try to make your callback as short as possible so you would catch up with the loading page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         HN
// @namespace    https://news.ycombinator.com/*
// @version      2024-02-02
// @description  For Hacker News
// @author       Bobby
// @match        https://news.ycombinator.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const mutations = [];
let timeout;
const recordObserver = new MutationObserver(ms => (mutations.push(...ms), clearTimeout(timeout), timeout = setTimeout(processMutations)));

function processMutations(){
    mutations.forEach(m => {
        if (m.type === "childList" && m.addedNodes) {
            m.addedNodes.forEach(target => {

                if (target.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    target.querySelectorAll(`.athing:not([read_123])`).forEach (element=> {

                        element.setAttribute(`read_123`, true);

                        element.style.background = '#00FF0055';

                        console.log(element.id);
                    });
                }


            });
        }
    });
}

recordObserver.observe(document, {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    characterData: false,
    subtree: true
});
```

Comment: Where can I find docs on "MutationObserver callbacks are async"? It doesn't mention on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation it's strange there's no mention of microtask, but i remember when i first learned about MutationObserver that was clearly mentioned. most probably it was MDN. i don't know there's no clear mention of that now

Comment: If this is the case, does that mean that I cannot rely on `MutationObserver` to get the appended nodes in order? For example, I can't rely on it to get incoming chat messages in the incoming order?

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation you are trying to watch page content returned from the server in your case? that's not mutations imho

Comment: No, by incoming chat messages, I meant messages being inserted into the page using HTML. Like imagine the YouTube super chat feature where super chats are inserted into the page with their various coloured backgrounds. I need to do something when such mutations occur.

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation i guess MutationObserver should work