Why not "export" the state and result of Promise?
EDIT: ok, I understand the problem with "Zalgo" (having an API that sometimes calls a callback synchronously and sometimes not). I'll remove this from my question and focus on the state and result of the Promise.

There have been plenty of questions about how to determine the state and result of a Promise synchronously, i.e. without awaiting or calling .then, and the response is always "no such method exists in the spec, but here's a trick..." and indeed there is a way to do this (here's a minimal example: https://gist.github.com/aayla-secura/af0cab39341ef0c4ec7fcf5dc9927c15).
Can someone clarify if and why it's a bad idea to save the state and result of a Promise externally so it can be inspected?

Background: I want to be able to determine if a Promise is already settled and what its state and result are synchronously so as to avoid unnecessary awaiting in my code. You might call that a micro-optimization, but it depends on how many times the code will await on a Promise that's already settled. Here's a simple benchmark:
async function foo(x) {
    return x+1;
}
function bar(x) {
    return x+1;
}

console.time('async');
(async() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        await foo(1);
    }
    console.timeEnd('async');
})();


console.time('sync');
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    bar(1);
}
console.timeEnd('sync');

On my laptop produces:
sync: 0.40087890625 ms
async: 25.669921875 ms

Yeah, not huge difference in most cases, but I believe it depends on the use-case. And the question remains: is there anything wrong with creating a stateful Promise, and if so why?

"so by the time the Promise constructor returns, the executor would have ran" - Unless the promise is settled synchronously, the asynchronous operation that is wrapped by the promise would still be in progress, so the promise will be in pending state by the time the executor function ends.

You are saying you want to know if the promise has been settled, but then bar function has nothing to do with promises. How are the two related?

@Yousaf Yes, but what I'm saying is that if we use a method whereby we save the relevant resolve and reject callbacks from inside the executor, they are guaranteed to be defined when the constructor finished. I'm not saying the Promise will be resolved by then.

@KrzysztofKrzeszewski I don't understand your question. "then bar function"... are you referring to my dummy functions that I use to compare execution time of synchronous vs asynchronous code that just awaits on a resolved promise (result of foo)? The relevance is I'm showing that awaiting on an already resolved Promise adds overhead which is unnecessary.

If your question is WHY are resolve/reject functions are exposed as parameters to the executor function, I can only give you my opinion. Most of the times, they are supposed to be called once the wrapped asynchronous operation ends. In other words, they are mostly required inside the executor function. If you have a particular requirement where you want to resolve/reject the promise without waiting for the asynchronous operation to end, then this use case is rare, at least in my experience. In general, if some value is available asynchronously, then it should be accessed asynchronously.

@Yousaf An example use case is a "Waitable" type that is created and can be passed around. The code that has access to it can resolve or reject it, or inspect its state and result and await on it if needed. It's not always practical to resolve or reject the Promise from inside a single function that's passed to the Promise constructor. Would you disagree?

see Promise.withResolvers for your second revelation

@JaromandaX Thanks, glad to see it's been recently implemented.

I don't see how the "background" section (about inspectable state) is relevant to why resolve/reject are not exposed on the Promise (or a separate Deferred object). I hope the answers on the duplicates provide the explanation you're looking for.

@Bergi I guess my mistake is asking two somewhat separate questions into one... And the "duplicate" questions don't really answer all of my questions. They talk about downsides of the deferred pattern, but not why we can't have a stateful Promise where the state and result can be inspected.

@AaylaSecura Ah, yes, I didn't spot the second question about exposing the state. You might want to ask that as a separate question, after taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/45378267/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/24881345/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/23447876/1048572. Basically the reason is to prevent people from shooting themselves into the foot. I doubt the performance gains you hope for will be worthwhile.
